# Http Request headers not working properly, Angular 5

Tags: angular, api, http

I'm building an Angular 5 app where I am making an api request to an external server. I am trying to hard-code some headers, including content-type and an 'x-api-key'. In postman, the request works perfectly, so I know I have the correct information.

The issue is that I will add headers to the request, and when I console.log the request options it will show them in an array, but upon inspecting it in the network tab, it will only show the titles of the headers I included (content-type and x-api-key) and not the values themselves. I receive a 403/forbidden error, so I know the API recognizes the request but I"m not authorized to get the information. See below- 
[image]

Here's how I'm adding the headers:

auth.service.ts

```
  createAuthorizationHeader(headers: Headers) {
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('username:password')); 
    headers.append('x-api-key', '...');
    headers.append('Content-type', 'application/json')
 }
```

then where I call the api-

```
 logInUser(signInData: { username: string, password: string }): Observable<Response> {
  let headers2 = new Headers();
  this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers2);
  return this.authService.post('http://api_url.com', signInData,{
  headers: headers2
})
```

When I console.log the request options:
[image]

How might I restructure things so that the full values of my headers will be recognized in my request? Any information will help!  THANK YOU

p.s. I previously was using a Rails API, so in order to connect I would use the Angular2Token Module along with the 'cors' gem to make requests, so I am trying to transition away from it.

Comment: Are there any CORS errors in your console?

Comment: @AshishRanjan Yes there are- it reads something like ' [request] has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.'

Comment: Are you setting proper `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in your API?

Comment: I'm not in control of the API but I believe so because I can access it from Postman, API tester

Comment: When using Postman you are accessing the API through same origin(you access API directly through API URL), when using your frontend app, a different origin is accessing the API(Front end URL is internall access API URL) so you get those errors.

Comment: So this API, Is your app fully dependent on this or you are using this just for some small specific purpose?

Comment: Ah I see, so possibly it's the API not set to Access-Control-Allow-Origin causing this? Or might it be a configuration I need to make to work with it? And should I get rid of Angular2-token? And yes, all my user data/etc is dependent on this API

Comment: CORS might be an issue, but clearly the request headers are empty, which is an issue on it's own. try using "HttpHeaders" instead of "Headers".... since "Headers"  has been deprecated.

Comment: `new HttpHeaders();` and  `headers = headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('username:password'));` and  `headers = headers.append('x-api-key', '...');` and so on...

Comment: I believe that it is `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` causing the issue, You are using `RequestOptions()`  for setting Objects right? For now you are seeing Provisional Headers, they are not real. First fix your CORS issue I think you should be good to go!

Comment: @LaurenAH have you tried `headers.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('username:password'));` instead of `headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('username:password'));` this????